# Data is not appending in the div in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am fetching data from database using jquery ajax in laravel. 
But data is not appending in the div. 
Here is my route

```
Route::get('teammessage/{id}','PublicController@teamMessage')->name('teammessage');
```

Here is my controller

```
public function teamMessage($id){
    $projectId = $id;
    TeamChat::where('projectproposal_id', $projectId)->update(array('unread' => 0));
    $teamChatInfo = TeamChat::where('projectproposal_id',$projectId)
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->get(); 
    return Response::json(['success'=>$teamChatInfo]);
}
```

Here is my div

```
<div id="test">   
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code

```
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  loadData();
 function loadData() {
    var id=$('#projectId').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/teammessage/'+id,
      success: function(value){
         console.log(value);
       $('#test').html(value)
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

I can see those data in my console by writing `console.log(value);` inside success function.
Thank you .

Comment: You're trying to set `$("#test")`'s html to `value`, which is an object of `{ success => [...]}`, where `success` is a `Collection` of `TeamChat` models, converted to `JSON`... Not overly surprising that nothing is happening. Try looping, or returning a single entity, and using `$("#test").html(value.success)` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  loadData();
 function loadData() {
    var id=$('#projectId').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/teammessage/'+id,
      success: function(value){
       $(value.success).each(function(e,k){
       $('#test').append(value.success[e].yourdata);
       });

      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

### Edit

```
$('#test').append("<p>"+value.success[e].yourdata+"</p>");
```

Comment: it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: I have updated my code, Please try. Also can you please paste your json?

Comment: it is working now. But problem is all data is showing in a same line. Can you please say me how i can add new line after every print.

Comment: Wrap your data in <p></p>. It will generate new line for each data. @Fokrule

Comment: Welcome brother. :) @Fokrule